# Performance: I/O operations in a loop?

Tags: c#, networking

I have to implement a loop that continuously reads data from a device via network. Now I'm wondering if it is efficient to implement it like this:

1. Start a worker thread.
2. In this worker thread, loop until a flag is set.
3. Within the loop, perform **synchronous** I/O.

Does this have any performance impact compared to asynchronous I/O?

Comment: Exactly - the next loop iteration only fires when the synchronous I/O is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"It depends."

If the network device is producing a steady stream of data then it makes sense to have a thread dedicated to servicing it synchronously. The thread blocks until data is available, then reads and processes the data. That thread can notify the main thread as necessary.

If the device produces data only infrequently, then it might make more sense to use asynchronous requests. Issue an async read call in the main thread, then go about your business. When data becomes available, then it's read by the async callback and processed as appropriate, and a new async read is issued.

That's the general rule I use: lots of data, then dedicate a thread. Infrequent data, use async. That's not a hard and fast rule, but it's where I start.

There is a performance impact either way. It's a matter of tradeoffs. A persistent thread will consume resources (primarily stack space, and whatever data the thread proc uses) for its entire lifetime. If the thread is spending most of its time waiting on input, that's not a very efficient use of resources.

On the other hand, it takes some non-zero amount of time to issue an asynchronous read request. If you expect data infrequently (say, no more than once per second), then the overhead involved in those asynchronous read requests is probably irrelevant. But if you have a continuous stream of data and you're issuing hundreds or thousands of asynchronous read requests per second, then the overhead is going to affect performance. When you're doing that many read requests, you essentially have a dedicated thread processing the input, so you might as well just simplify your program and create a persistent thread.

Comment: Thanks, then I'll have to go with asynchronous I/O and continuations.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it has impact:

- creating new thread consumes memory and time to initialize the thread
- thread management (sleep/wake)
- thread synchronization to consume read data.

If it's possible you better implement asynchronous reads. It's much more elegand solution.

Though a lot of applications use your described approach and doesn't have significant performance issues, so it's possible solution and *the main issues aren't performance here* I would say (if you don't create new thread for every new file or user every second).